# How to set site specific Error Log files in PHP under IIS

Tags: php, iis, error-reporting

On Apache, vhosts can be configured with their own error log file, like so:

```
ErrorLog "my-site-log-dir/error_log.log"
```

How would this be done when hosting PHP under IIS?

Answer (score 1):

> [SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4764452/1892635)
>
> To report errors in the Event viewer, go to your php.ini and make sure
> logging is on.
>
> log_errors = On
>
> then enable error_log to write to syslog (with is the Event Viewer on
> Windows machines)
>
> error_log = syslog
>
> http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/logging_php_to_windows_event_log

If using 'shared' hosting windows hosting then you most likely have a control panel that should have some kind of logging, otherwise see method above.

Comment: Hi, I want to have PHP create site specific error log files in each sites directory.  As you can do with ease under Apache.  Not use the event log in windows.  I have access to IIS, and the whole server.  Ideally I'd like to do this via a setting in the web.config file for the site.